# Searching an 2D array row in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am searching an **2D array** that has **1** and **0**. If there is an adjacent 3 to a 0, the 0 gets converted to a 3. I have figured out how to search a row once, but I would like the same for loop to repeat until all the 0's have been converted to 3. Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is a visual depiction. So if I am searching the 2nd row, I will find the first 0 touching a 3, but then I want to go through the same row and find the next 0 that is touching a 3. I hope that clarifies! :)

1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1

1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1

1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1

etc.

I start the search on row with index 1 and I find the first 0 that touches a 3 and convert it to a 3. So I have the following, I then need to go back and repeat the process until the remainding 0 is converted to a 3 and then repeat for each row:

1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1

1 0 1 1 0 3 1 1

1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1

```
    public boolean searchRows(){
    boolean found = false;
    for (int c = 0; c < cave[rowIndex].length; c++){

        if(cave[rowIndex][c]==0){
            if (cave[rowIndex-1][c] == 3){
                cave[rowIndex][c] = 3;
                found=true;
            }
            else if(cave[rowIndex][c-1] == 3){
                    cave[rowIndex][c] = 3;}
            else {found=false;}
        }
    }   
    return found;
}
```

Comment: why would the for loop use `cave[0].length` on the `while` condition?  why wouldn't it be `cave[rowIndex].length`?

Comment: Do they not equal the same value? It's the same as the number of columns in this example.

Comment: if that is always the case it wont be a problem I guess, what is the issue?  I cannot understand..  give example of the result and why it's wrong

Comment: The row finds the first 0 to convert to 3. Once the for loop is complete, there is a new 0 that is touching a 3, the one in the column previous to the first 0 that got converted. I need to find a way to reiterate the for loop until there are no more 0's to convert. I hope that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: you mean you will find a touching 3 when scanning the second row (index 1), then you want to continue on that SAME row or you want to scan row 3 (index 2)?

Comment: I should specify that I am working on row with index 1.

Comment: Yes, until all the values that need to be converted are done.

Comment: but are you only going to be looking at row index 1?

Comment: in your example you show good table data for the problem but you should show what you want and what you are getting.

Comment: No eventually I will repeat the same process for each row. Just trying to figure out one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your for loop is working fine to go through the one row. It looks like you aren't checking all of the possible elements that could be touching the one you are currently looking at. It looks like you are checking the element directly above it and the one directly to the left of it. You should be checking whatever other directions your problem asks for as well. You should also be checking that you aren't going to be checking an array index that doesn't exist so that you don't get an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error. Along with that make sure you are are setting your found boolean anytime that you actually find a zero that will be turned into a 3. Currently you are only setting the found to true in one case and not the other.